# Pytest - pass paths for data and testing directories

Tags: python, pytest, config

I would like to test a package that requires large data files as input, and creates / deletes folder directory structures. Currently to test this is specify the paths at which to test (e.g. create and delete files in) as well as a path to the data.

It is important the user supplies paths for testing that are non-existent / empty, as the test folder is deleted if it already exists. As such I would like the user to add these paths in a pytest config file where sufficient warning can be given in comments. For compability with existing organisational configs, I would like to do this in the pytest.ini if possible.

I've looked around but cannot find the best way to do this (/ if it is even possible in pytest.ini, or pyconf.py must be used). Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of warning when a non-empty directory is given as input, I think that [running each test in a temporary directory](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html) would be a better solution to the larger problem of not accidentally deleting important files.  Besides not having to worry about dangerous user input, this approach also makes debugging easier: each test runs in its own directory, so when a test fails, you can go back and see the files that led to that failure.

To get this working, you just need to add the `tmp_path` fixture to the relevant tests (as explained in the link above).  Alternatively, you may be interested in a plugin I wrote called [`pytest_tmp_files`](https://pytest-tmp-files.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).  This plugin provides a `tmp_files` fixture that behaves just like `tmp_path`, except that it can fill in the temporary directory with any files/subdirectories you specify before the test starts.  This is especially useful for parametrized testing.  For example, here's two ways to test the `shutil.rmtree()` function:

```py
import pytest
from shutil import rmtree

def test_rmtree_1(tmp_path):
    p = tmp_path / 'd'
    p.mkdir()
    assert p.exists()

    rmtree(p)
    assert not p.exists()

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'tmp_files', [
            # Empty directory:
            {'d': {'type': 'dir', 'contents': {}}},

            # Directory containing a text file:
            {'d/f': 'lorem'},

            # Directory containing a text file in a subdirectory:
            {'d/d2/f': 'ipsum'},
        ],
        indirect=True,
)
def test_rmtree_2(tmp_files):
    p = tmp_files / 'd'
    assert p.exists()

    rmtree(p)
    assert not p.exists()
```

Note how the second test easily covers a number of different directory structures, while the first only covers one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *why* you would need the user to supply an empty path instead of handling it on your own. But I suppose that's not your question.

Instead of assuming the user will read a comment, I would recommend adding a fixture to protect against it within `conftest.py` --

```
import pytest
from pathlib import Path

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def verify_user_dir_is_empty():
    user_dir = Path("/some/path/here")
    is_empty = next(user_dir.iterdir(), True)
    if is_empty is not True:
        pytest.fail("[Error] Directory specified not empty.")
```